# how to convert character time to numeric value in R

Tags: r

I have following column in r data frame in character format

```
 time
 12:45:34
 01:23:00
 21:32:00
 56:32:00
```

I want it in following format

```
 time
 12.45
 1.23
 21.32
 56.32
```

I did following

```
 gsub("*\\:[0-9]", ".", df$time)
```

But,does not give what is intended.

Comment: Are you sure you really want it this way? A minute and twenty-three seconds is well different from 1.23 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

We can capture the numbers (`\\d+`) from the start (`^`) as a group (`(..)`) followed by `:` followed by another set of numbers as a group, then in the replacement use the backreference of the captured group and dot in between

```
df1$time <- as.numeric(sub("^(\\d+):(\\d+).*", "\\1.\\2", df1$time))
df1$time
#[1] 12.45  1.23 21.32 56.32
```

---

Or get the substring with `substr` and replace the ":" with `.`, convert to `numeric`

```
as.numeric(sub(":", ".", substr(df1$time, 1, 5)))
```